# Nginx include directive having no effect

Tags: nginx

## Goal:

Serve several low-traffic domains (mostly of static content) from my VPS.  Currently, I'm using Nginx under FreeBSD.

## Problem:

My `include` statement seemingly is entirely ignored.  Even if I put gibberish in an included `.conf` file, `sudo nginx -t` says everything is all good.  All of my domains therefore serve the same default landing page, which really should only be found if you go straight to the server's IP address.

If I go to `http://example.com/example.com/html/`, the page I want to be shown at `http://example.com` appears.  I can also go to `http://www.example.com/domain2.com/html/` to view what should be at `http://domain2.com`.

**What am I missing that makes all sites go to the same page?**

## Files:

### `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user  www;
worker_processes  1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    #Setup multiple domains
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

    #Default Server, for going straight to the IP address
    server {
        listen  80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen  443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        server_name _;

        #ssl on; #currently off for the bare IP
        #ssl_certificate        /etc/nginx/ssl/default.crt;
        #ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/ssl/default.key;

        access_log  /var/nginx/log/access.log;
        root    /var/www/;
        index   index.php index.htm index.html;
   }

}
```

### `/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com.conf`

*(really a symlink for `/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf`)*

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen  [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    root /var/www/example.com/html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location = / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    #include /usr/local/etc/nginx/common.conf #for future use for common parts of the server block for all domains
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The include path:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
```

And the file:

```
/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com.conf
```

are in **different directories**.

---

You can include relative to the `nginx` configuration directory with:

```
include sites-enabled/*.conf;
```

Or specify the absolute location as:

```
include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
```

Comment: …to think all that trouble was from me forgetting to change the path to match where my files actually were.

Comment: Note for other people: make sure you don't start your path with a slash if you're using a relative directory.